# How to run a function when all the data loaded?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I process thousands of points asynchronously in ArcGIS JS API. In the main function, I call functions processing individual features, but I need to finalize the processing when all the features are processed. There should be an event for this, though I didn't find any and I'm afraid it even doesn't exist - it would be hard to state that the last item processed was *the last* of all. [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) should do this, but I don't use jQuery, just Dojo. Closest what I found in Dojo was [Fetch and its OnComplete](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/fetchmultiple.html), but as far as I know it's about fetching data from AJAX, not from other JS function.

The only workaround idea I have now is to measure how many features are to be processed and then fire when the output points array reaches desired length, but I need to count the desired number at first. But how to do it at loading? Tracking the data to the point where they are read from server would mean modifying functions I'm not supposed to even know, which is not possible.

EDIT - some of my code:

```
addData: function (data) {
    dojo.addOnLoad(
        this.allData = data,
        this._myFunction()
    );
},
```

Some comments:

- `data` is an array of graphics
- when I view `data` in debugger, its count is 2000, then 3000, then 4000...
- without `dojo.addOnLoad`, the count started near zero, now it's around 2000, but still a fraction of the real number
- `_myFunction()` processes all the 2000...3000...4000... graphics in `this._allData`, and returns wrong results because it needs them all to work correctly
- I need to delay execution of `_myFunction()` until all data load, perhaps by some other event instead of `dojo.addOnLoad`.

Workarounds I already though of:

a) [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

This is clearly a wrong option - any magic number of miliseconds to wait for would fail to save me if the `data` contains too much items, and it would delay even cases of a single point in the array.

b) length-based delay

I could replace the event with something like this:

```
if(data.length == allDataCount) {
    this._myFunction();
}
setTimeout(this._thisFunction, someDelay);
```

or some other implementation of the same, through a loop or a counter incremented in asynchronously called functions. Problem is how to make sure the `allDataCount` variable is definitive and not just the number of features leaded until now.

EDIT2: pointing to deferreds and promises by [@tik27](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656934/1801588) definitely helped me, but the best I found on converting synchronous code to a deferred was [this simple example](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/06/understanding-deferreds-and-promises-in-dojo/). I probably misunderstood something, because it doesn't work any better than the original, synchronous code, the `this.allData` still can't be guaranteed to hold all the data. The loading function now looks like this:

```
addData: function (data) {
        var deferred = new Deferred();
        this._addDataSync(data, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }
        });
        deferred.promise.then(this._myFunction());
    },

    _addDataSync: function (data, callback) {
        callback(this.allData = data);
    },
```

I know most use cases of deferred suppose requesting data from some server. But this is the first time where I can work with data without breaking functions I shouldn't change, so tracking the data back to the request is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of solved my problem, delaying the call of my layer's constructor until the map loads completely and the `"onUpdateEnd"` event triggers. This is probably the way how it should be properly done, so I post this as an answer and not as an edit of my question. On the other hand, I have no control over other calls of my class and I would prefer to have another line of defense against incomplete inputs, or at least a way to tell whether I should complain about incomplete data or not, so I keep the answer unaccepted and the question open for more answers.

This didn't work when I reloaded the page, but then [I figured out how to properly chain event listeners together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35773708/1801588), so I now can combine `"onUpdateEnd"` with extent change or any other event. That's perfectly enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

addonload is to wait for the dom.
If you are waiting for a function to complete to run another function deferred/promises are what is used.

Would need more info on your program to give you more specific answers..

Comment: Sorry for a delay in response and thanks for pointing in the right direction. I combined [this example](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/06/understanding-deferreds-and-promises-in-dojo/) with my code and it works; probably I'll have to add dojo/promise/all as well, but I know what I need and where to learn it. I consider adding the code solving my problem as another answer, but your answer will stay the accepted one. +1

Comment: Bad news, I didn't manage to make the deferred-based code work. I edited my question with my new code.