# How to link "extent-change" and "update-end" events in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

In ArcGIS JS API I need to trigger a method of my class when the processing after an extent change is complete. I didn't find any special event for this. `extent-change` triggers too early, when the data are not loaded yet. `update-end` is triggered also by the function I want to call, making an endless loop. So what I need is to link the two events together, the second one just once. But how?

Most of my events look like this:

```
this.events.push(on(this.map, "extent-change", lang.hitch(this, this._foo)));
```

This is not suitable for event linking, so I need to make the linked event some other way. What I've tried:

```
_foo: function () {
    function fooEvent() {
        this._bar();
        dojo.disconnect(updateHandle);
    }
    var updateHandle = dojo.connect(map, "onUpdateEnd", fooEvent());
}
```

`_bar` is the method I want to run on the end of the extent change. However, `this` in the event handler means something else, not the class containing the function. I also tried the classname I declared in the `declare` statement, but with no luck.

`_foo()` and `_bar()` are in the same class (let's call it `"foobar/baz"`). However, inside of the `fooEvent()` is not its subclass as I hoped - when I try to use `this.inherited` within it, it's undefined. Another way I try is to add `event` argument to the handler, but it's undefined as well. So unless there is some better way, I need to understand how to get the object of `"foobar/baz"` class.

Another way I tried was to use `lang.hitch` once more, in one of the following ways:

```
//through the cluster event
var updateHandle = dojo.connect(map, "onUpdateEnd", lang.hitch(this, clusterEvent));

//or directly calling _bar()
var updateHandle = dojo.connect(map, "onUpdateEnd", { langh:lang.hitch(this, this._bar), disc:dojo.disconnect(updateHandle)});

//or through on, leaving a rouge event listener
dojo.on(map, "onUpdateEnd", lang.hitch(this, this._bar));
```

None of them returns any clear error and though the `_bar()` method seemed to work for some time, it doesn't work now - this is true for all three of the previous. I don't understand what these listeners do.

Comment: you mean the method _foo: is declared inside a class A and your _bar() method in Class B for example ?

Comment: @bRIMOsBor: both in the same class. I usually just use this to reference other methods and properties in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by flattening the event listeners. First, I made a flag `_reloadFlag`, initialized in the constructor as `false` and then changed to `true` whenever I want to call `_bar`, like in `_foo`. `_bar` now starts with a test of `_reloadFlag` either setting it to `false` or returning nothing. The event listeners now look like this:

```
this.events.push(on(this.map, "extent-change", lang.hitch(this, this._foo)));
this.events.push(on(this.map, "update-end", lang.hitch(this, this._bar)));
```